# Test reviews counted as reviews

Tags: discussion, review, review-audit

For close votes for instance, we are limited to 20 reviews per 11-12 hours, which is not a lot.

However when you have a test close vote (the ones designed to check that you're not voting without thinking), they count as one of the 20 votes ! Why is that ? Based on their role, shouldn't they not be included in the total reviews done ?

Comment: Related meta.SE threads: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/224209/review-audits-should-not-be-counted-to-the-count-of-daily-reviews http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/197875/why-do-audits-count-toward-the-maximum-number-of-reviews-in-a-queue

Comment: @NajibIdrissi Oh, thanks. Should I delete my question ?

Comment: If you want, it's not necessary. In general I believe it's allowed to have threads on metas of different sites about the same topic (though in this case I don't know if there's much of a point, I doubt this kind of feature will be tuned to each site separately).

Comment: One advantage of having the topic also on per-site meta might be that very probably there are users, which are aware of meta.math.Se but they do not know about existence of math.SE. If such user will search for this question on this meta, even if a post on a local meta only directs them to meta.SE, it is still useful for them.